# Get Dynamic PHP Form ID using Ajax in another File

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

1. There are 3 files in question.
2. One is a dashboard.php file which contains a script tag to point to course_mg.js file.
3. course_mg.js file uses ajax to GET course_mg.php file to display list of students.

So here are the two above mentioned file [not including dashboard.php as it has only script tag but keep in mind it is the main page where ajax is being used].

**course_mg.php**

```
<?php

    require('../../inc/connect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['delete_course'])){
        $id = $_POST['delete_course'];
        $sql_del = "DELETE FROM courses WHERE courses.id = $id";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_del) or die($mysqli->error);
    if($result){
        header('location: ../dashboard.php');
    } else{
        echo "Error in deleting user";
    }
}

?>

<div class="dash_head">Manage Course</div>
<div class="card mx-5 my-5 px-5">

    <h3 class="h3">View Courses Info</h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover text-center">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Created_At</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php
        $offset = (1 - 1) * 3;
        $row_count = 3;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM courses"; // order by id limit $row_count offset $offset"    
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);  
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['ID'];
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Name']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row['Created_At']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="POST" action="php/course_mg.php">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm bg-danger text-white" type="submit" name="delete_course" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>">Delete</button>
                        </form>  
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
        }
    ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <h6><em>List of Available Courses</em></h6>
    </div>
    <div>
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link disabled" href="#">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link disabled" href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**course_mg.js**

```
document.getElementById('course_mg').addEventListener('click', load_managecourse);

    function load_managecourse(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', 'php/course_mg.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function () {

            if(this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('showresults').innerHTML = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById('ID').addEventListener('submit', deleteCourse(this.value));

                function deleteCourse($id) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log($id);
                    var name = document.getElementById(ID).value;

                    console.log(name);

                    var params = "delete_course=" + name;

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhr.open('POST', 'php/course_mg.php', true);

                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        if(this.status == 200){
                            document.getElementById('userAdded').style.padding = "15px 0px";
                            document.getElementById('userAdded').style.borderRadius = "200px";
                            document.getElementById('userAdded').innerHTML = `
                                Course Deleted
                            `;
                        }
                    }

                    xhr.send(params);
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
```

4. Now this is working perfectly in PHP but failing in AJAX precisely because I am not able to figure out how to get dynamic php form id in javascript.

For instance this is what I want to do:

```
<form id="dynamic_id_based_on_user_id_extracted_from_database">
 <button type="submit" name="delete_course" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>">Delete</button>
</form>
```

There is one value I want of formID and another the value mentioned in value of button in the **course_mg.js**
The code for this purpose starts from below mentioned line: before that it's loading the same **course_mg.php** page to get the page, afterwards on clicking delete it is trying to delete the user.

```
document.getElementById('ID').addEventListener('submit', deleteCourse(this.value));
```

I want to know how can I get 'ID' placeholder dynamically from the above form?

Comment: You don't show your HTML, but are you sure there's an element with an id attribute of "ID"? Is it a unique value? Also in at least one case you didn't quote "ID" so are trying to pass a variable of that name instead.

Comment: @miken32 He wants to know how you can get the ID placeholder dynamically...

Comment: Do you simply mean `document.form[0].id`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: You're doing a `console.log($id)`. Is that showing you the correct ID? Why not just use that? `document.getElementById($id)`?

Comment: @FrankerZ It isn't showing anything.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't know where to use that. I want the 'ID' to be dynamic. Meaning say the user_id in database is 1 or 2, so I want the form id to be form_1 or form_2 respectively. This I want to getElementById(here). I am new to javascript or web programming in general and don't know how to get this. I then want the button id[which is dynamic as well] to use for deletion of users/data in mysql.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for the link. I will be transitioning to PDO once I grasp the basics.

Comment: But because its dynamic you need to ask the `<form>` what its `id` attribute is.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't get what you mean by that.